# Not able to get an input from the stdin in python 3

Tags: python, input, stdin

I am learning python from a platform where the console or the tool uses a automatic input kind of thing, there is mentioned that USE `STDIN` for inputs, I am trying `sys.stdin.readline()` and `sys.stdin.readline().split()` but nothing seems to be working, please help me with the same.

thank you

the hints are like this..

```
Sample Test Cases

**Sample Input**
=======================================
3

1 9


22 31


90 103
========================================
Sample Output
========================================

Difference Not in Range

[22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31]

Out of Range

========================================
```

I am trying `sys.stdin.readline()` and `sys.stdin.readline().split()` 
tried to give manual inputs
tried `int(input())`

CODE:

```
import sys

# Read the variable from STDIN
#begin is the beginning and end is for storing the end value
#taking the user input for the start and end points of the integer
t=int(sys.stdin.readline())
l=[]
while t:
   n=1
   a=int(sys.stdin.readline().split())
   start=int(a[0])
   end=int(a[1])
   if (end-start<10 and end-start>10 and start<=0,end>=100):
       print("Difference Not in Range!")
       if start<=0 and end>=100:
           print("Out of Range!")
   else:
       while start<end:
           start=start+1
           l.append(start)
# Output the variable to STDOUT
       STDOUT=print(l)`
```

Answer (score 0):

You're reading from stdin correctly, so if you're not seeing output, the issue is with the program logic.

Here's what you have now on a minimal input from stdin:

```py
line = sys.stdin.readline()
print(int(line))
```

```sh
% echo 1  | python readlines.py
1
```

Here's a slightly different approach:

```py
numbers = sys.stdin.read().split()
print(numbers)
```

```sh
% echo 1 2 3 2 | python readlines.py
['1', '2', '3', '2']
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to cast a List of strings into a integer.

```
a=int(sys.stdin.readline().split())
```

maybe this would do the job:

```
a=str(sys.stdin.readline()).split()
```

because you cast it in the two following lines into integers